# Are low volume products RoHS exempt in the EU?

Tags: rohs

Are small companies that intend to sell less than 100 units in the EU market required to comply with RoHS?

This Forbes article seems to state that exemptions are possible till 2017?

> REACH and RoHS both started with companies shipping high volumes of product into the EU, giving exemptions to lower-volume companies, but eventually all companies conducting business in Europe will need to comply (in most cases by 2017)."

*([source](http://www.forbes.com/sites/amywestervelt/2012/05/10/how-international-regulations-are-changing-american-supply-chains/))*

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question. What else do you need to know?

Comment: I'm curious if anyone here has done this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In practice, it would be very difficult to get exempted, and wouldn't be worth the trouble in the case of electronic items.

Products also have to conform to the EMC requirements.

Comment: This Forbes article seems to state that exemptions are possible till 2017? (see question edit)

Answer (score 0):

I've been doing my own research, and nowhere have I seen any reference to small-volume exemptions, unfortunately. e.g.

http://www.newark.com/pdfs/RohsTechManual_v2.pdf

http://www.bis.gov.uk/assets/nmo/docs/rohs/support-literature/nmo_technicalbrochure_acc4.pdf

http://www.bis.gov.uk/nmo/enforcement/rohs-home/due-diligence

(This and WEEE compliance really badly affects small-volume electronics in the EU, I think)